# How to map keybindings to find-file?

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, find-file

How I can map keybindings to `find-file` since there is no
`find-file-mode-map` or something like that?

I am using the [vertico](https://github.com/minad/vertico) minimalistic vertical completion UI.

Comment: What do you mean? `find-file` is a function that is bound to `C-x C-f`: it just opens a file. It is not a major mode, so certainly it does not have an associated mode map. You might want to explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want the binding  `<DEL>` to `backward-kill-sexp` but only when I'm in the `find-file` command.

Comment: Edit your question to mention your use of vertico. I rejected that edit because it was signed with a different user name from EasterEgg. It wasn't clear that you were editing your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find-file` typically ends up calling `read-file-name` which often uses the minibuffer to read the name but can use graphical file pickers if so configured. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-File-Names.html) for more details. In particular you probably want the link to Minibuffer Completions.

There are a large number of packages, both built-in and add on, which expand on this. These include helm, ido, ivy, vertico. Some of these have their own keymaps and some just use the minibuffer-mode-map.

So there is no one answer to the question, it depends on the user configuration.

Edit:
The OP tells us they use vertico.
One of the philosophical differences between packages like helm and ivy on one hand and vertico and selectrum on the other is that the former wrap the completion system whilst the latter don't.

This tends to mean that with vertico you have the same keymap for all your completions. This gets you consistency but makes tweaks for particular situations harder. One approach is to always bind <kbd>DEL</kbd> to a function and let that function figure out if it is completing a filename, in which case call `backward-kill-sexp` otherwise call `backwards-kill-char`. The [vertico-directory](https://github.com/minad/vertico/blob/main/extensions/vertico-directory.el#L43) package has a function `vertico-directory--completing-file-p` whose documentation implies it will help, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: well, I don't know if this will help, I use vertico. But I haven't found any useful variable for this situation.

Comment: What situation? Your question is unclear. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map`. Try out the following test:

```
(defun find-file-test ()
  (interactive)
  (message "test works!"))

(define-key minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map
            [C-backspace] #'find-file-test)
```

Comment: It failed, I tried to press `C-<DEL>` and nothing happened, I'm using vertico btw, but I haven't found any vertico-specific variable to this

Comment: Take a look at the vertico documentation. I believe it replaces all the mini buffer maps with its own. Maybe `vertico-map`?

Comment: Yeah, there is a `vertico-map` variable, but I only want my binding to work when I'm using the `find-file` command.

Comment: I would suggest creating a GitHub issue on the vertico project, since your question is specific to that. You may also want to look at [vertico-directory](https://github.com/minad/vertico/blob/main/extensions/vertico-directory.el).

Comment: `C-<backspace>` and `C-<delete>` are not the same thing.

Comment: @NickD I know, but the backspace key is described as `DEL`: 
"DEL (translated from <backspace>) runs the command evil-backward-char
"

Comment: At least before the question was changed, this answers it (i.e., as originally posed), and regardless of the key used in the `define-key`. The point is that this answer correctly identifies that you need to bind the key in that keymap - for your original question. Now that you've said you use Vertico, that answer might no longer apply. This is the problem of poorly specified questions and "evolving" them to get closer to what you really meant.

Comment: @Drew Blame me, not the OP, for the edit to add that they are using vertico. I agree about the poorly specified question. My edit was an attempt to clarify the question rather than evolve it.